# Android Homescreen Widget

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, android-widget

I am experiencing some issues with recording audio. I have created a widget button that is supposed to initiate audio recording when clicked, and stop the recording after a few seconds. However, the button doesn't seem to be working as intended. Can you please provide me with some assistance in resolving this issue?

```
class RecordService() : Service() {

    companion object {
        const val START_RECORDING_ACTION = "START_RECORDING"
    }

    private var recorder: MediaRecorder? = null

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when (intent?.action) {
            START_RECORDING_ACTION -> startRecording()
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    private fun startRecording() {
        // Check if another recording is in progress
        if (recorder != null) {
            return
        }

      Log.d("RECORD","STARTED")

        // Create a new MediaRecorder and start recording
        recorder = MediaRecorder()
        recorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        recorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        recorder?.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        recorder?.setOutputFile(getOutputFile().absolutePath)
        recorder?.prepare()
        recorder?.start()

        Handler().postDelayed({
            recorder?.stop()
            recorder?.release()
            recorder = null
        },5000)

        Log.d("RECORD","STOPPED")

    }

    private fun getOutputFile(): File {
        // Create a new file in the app's cache directory to store the recorded audio
        val fileName = "recording_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4"
        return File(cacheDir, fileName)
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Stop and release the MediaRecorder when the service is destroyed
        recorder?.stop()
        recorder?.release()
        recorder = null
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

```
class RecordWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {



    @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout")
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {


        appWidgetIds.forEach { appWidgetId ->
            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an OnClickListener to the button
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(
                R.id.record_button,
                getRecordPendingIntent(context)
            )
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }

    }

    private fun getRecordPendingIntent(context: Context): PendingIntent {
        // Create an Intent to start a service for recording audio
        val intent = Intent(context, RecordService::class.java)
        intent.action = RecordService.START_RECORDING_ACTION

        // Create a PendingIntent to start the service when the button is clicked
        return PendingIntent.getService(
            context,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    }

}
```

I have tried it in this way also. It is working fine but the audio is not present in the output file.

```
class RecordWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null

    @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout")
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {


        for (widgetIDs in appWidgetIds) {

            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, widgetIDs)

        }


    }

    private fun pendingIntent(
        context: Context?,

        action: String
    ): PendingIntent? {
        val intent = Intent(context, javaClass)
        intent.action = action
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        )
    }

    private fun updateAppWidget(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetId: Int
    ) {

        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.record_button, pendingIntent(context, "TOAST"))
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.stopBtn, pendingIntent(context, "STOP"))

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)

    }

    private fun updateWidgets(context: Context) {
        val manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        val ids = manager.getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(context, javaClass))

        ids.forEach { id ->
            updateAppWidget(context, manager, id)
        }
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)

        val action = intent?.action ?: ""


        if (action == "TOAST") {


            executorService.execute(object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
                    mediaRecorder?.reset()

                    mediaRecorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                    mediaRecorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)

                    val contextWrapper = ContextWrapper(context?.applicationContext)
                    val musicDirectory =
                        contextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
                    val file = File(musicDirectory, "recording10" + ".mp3").path

                    mediaRecorder?.setOutputFile(file)
                    mediaRecorder?.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)

                    try {
                        mediaRecorder?.prepare()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }


                    mediaRecorder?.start()
                }

            })



            Toast.makeText(context, "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


        } else if (action == "STOP") {

            executorService.execute(object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    mediaRecorder?.stop()
                    mediaRecorder?.release()

                    mediaRecorder = null
                }

            })


            Toast.makeText(context, "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            try {

//                val mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer()
//                val contextWrapper = ContextWrapper(context?.applicationContext)
//                val musicDirectory = contextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
//                val file = File(musicDirectory, "recording8" + ".mp3").path
//                Toast.makeText(context, file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file)
//                mediaPlayer.prepare()
//                mediaPlayer.start()
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: "However, the button doesn't seem to be working as intended." doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work as intended? Are there any errors?

Comment: I have solved the button problem. But the main problem is that the output of audio file doesn't contain any audio.